# R: Add new column based on character vector and existing column in dataframe with unique items

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to assign elements in the character vector to the dataframe based on matching information in the existing column.

Data frame with one column

`head(df, 5)`

```
       items
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        1
```

`tail(df, 5)`

```
120001  44
120002  44
120003  44
120004  44
120005  44
```

The character vector `chr_v` consists of 44 unique items.

````
chr_v <- c("T1_1", "C1_1", "T1_2", "A_1", "C_2", "C_3", "T1_3", "A_2", "C_4", 
"C_5", "C_6", "C_7", "C_8", "A_3", "C_9", 'C_10', "C_11", "A_4", 'C_12', "A_5", 
"C_13", "A_6", "A_7", "C_14", "C_15", "C_16", "T_4", "C_17", "C_18", "C_19", 'T_5', 
"C_20", "C_21", "T_6", "A_8", "C_22", "C_23", "C_24", "C_25", "C_26", "T_7", "T_8", 
'C_27', 'C_28')

The length of ```chr_v``` is 
length(chr_v)
[1] 44
````

There are 44 unique ordered items in column `items` in dataframe and 44 rows in the character vector. I want to create a new column by repeating each item in the character vector to the unique ordered item in the column of dataframe.

Expected Output:
`head(df, 5)`

```
       items    newitem
1        1      T1_1
2        1      T1_1
3        1      T1_1
4        1      T1_1
5        1      T1_1
```

`tail(df, 5)`

```
      items    newitem
120001  44      C_28
120002  44      C_28
120003  44      C_28
120004  44      C_28
120005  44      C_28
```

I checked the dimension of each items in the `df` with `table` command but the output is not ordered (even tried to `sort`). Therefore, I cannot use the output to simply repeat the items sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin provided a tidyverse solution. Here is a base R solution:

```
df$newitem <- sample_info[df$items]
```

Here the `dplyr` pendant:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(newitem = sample_info[items])
```

output:

```
   items newitem
1      1    T1_1
2      1    T1_1
3      1    T1_1
4      1    T1_1
5      1    T1_1
6     44    C_28
7     44    C_28
8     44    C_28
9     44    C_28
10    44    C_28
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(items = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L), newitem = c("T1_1", "T1_1", "T1_1", "T1_1", "T1_1", "C_28", 
"C_28", "C_28", "C_28", "C_28")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `enframe()` combined with a `left_join()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  left_join(enframe(chr_v), by = c("items" = "name"))
```

Comment: I like your solution using `enframe`!

Comment: I like your solution as well !!